# How would I go about making a variable that allows me to toggle an object's visibility in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, p5.js, tetris

I am using the p5.js library to create Tetris. When someone gets a line clear (that is, a full line has been filled with Tetris blocks) then the tiles that made that line fill up should be removed/turned off.

What would be the best way to do this? For all visibility aspects of a tile, I use a show() function that draws a rectangle to show the tile. Should I add a variable to the object and check if that is true because executing the show function? Or is there a built-in method or function that makes removing an object easy? I can't seem to find anything like this online

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer if we do not know how your tiles are represented in your program.

The method I recommend is to remove the tile from it's container structure altogether.

For example, if the state of your game is stored in a matrix, simply empty the cells that constitute a line. This way, your `show()` function should not be called at all.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the tile from the container will work, but if its difficult then there is another way.

Have a variable to track whether the tile is being used and have its default be true e.g `this.inPlay = true`
Only update and show a tile if its inplay is true:

```
if (tile.inPlay == true) {
    tile.update()
    tile.show()
}
'''
If you want to remove it, just set its inplay to false

PS. a great tutorial for p5.js is on youtube (made by the coding train)
PPS. just search 'coding train p5.js tutorial' on youtube
```